# Question about $f(z)=\exp (-\frac{1}{z^4})$

Tags: complex-analysis, cauchy-riemann-equations

Let $f(z)=\exp (-\frac{1}{z^4})$ for $z\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.

I know this is a famous example and got asked a lot
However my question is not about the origin, but what is the best way to actually show that this functions satisfies Cauchy Riemann everywhere? I only read  that it fulfills it everywhere but nowhere could I find an actual proof.
Because writing
$ z = x+iy$ and then expanding the denominator in the exponent and then dividing into real and imaginary part ist really exhausting. Is this the only way or is there some shortcut here?

Comment: It doesn't satisfy Cauchy Riemann at $0.$ It is not even continuous at $z=0$ on the complex plain.  It is interesting as an example of a real function, infinitely differentiable, which is not analytic, not a complex analytic function.

Comment: Exactly as Thomas says.  You should note that it is complex differentiable everywhere except at 0 though.

Comment: The easiest way is to develop general lemmas that combinations of analytic functions (sums, products, quotients, compositions) are themselves analytic. Then you can build up functions like this out of simpler pieces whose analyticity is easy to confirm.

Comment: @Thomas actually the partial derivatives in $x,y$ exist at zero and are zero, so $f$ does satisfy C-R at $0$ but is not complex differentiable there as is not continuous or at least locally integrable; this is a typical example of why in going from $C-R$ to complex differentiability, one imposes stronger conditions than strictly C-R (which just means partial derivatives in $x,y$ exist and satisfy a relation); it is open afaik to find weakest conditions for which C-R imply complex differentiability; see the Gray Morris paper for more: https://www.jstor.org/stable/2321164

Comment: @Conrad yes, I missed the $4$ rather than the usual $2$ for the usual real case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I think there is a bit of confusion about complex differentiability vs C-R and there are lots of subtle points, let's note that if we have $f: U \to \mathbb C$ a complex differentiable function in an open (domain) $U \subset \mathbb C$, then by the usual theorems, $f$ is infinitely differentiable, analytic and satisfies the C-R equations which are succintly written as $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=i\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$$

However, the converse is not true in the sense that if $f$ is defined in $U$, has partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y},\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ everywhere in $U$ and said partial derivatives satisfy the C-R above, then it does not follow that $f$ is complex differentiable in $U$ and $f(z)=\exp (-\frac{1}{z^4}), z \ne 0$, while $f(0)=0$ is such a counterexample as clearly $f$ is complex differentiable on $\mathbb C-0$ being a composition of complex differentiable functions there, so by part I above it does satisfy C-R there.

Now it is a straightforward exercise to show that  $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0)=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0)=0$ so indeed $f$ has partial derivatives everywhere in the plane, satisfies C-R everywhere too, but it is not complex differentiable everywhere and there are counterexamples where the points where such a function (partial derivatives everywhere, C-R everywhere) is not complex differentiable have non zero Lebesgue measure.

(Note that $f$ above is separately continuous and real differentiable at $0$ in $x$ and $y$ as $f(x+i0)=e^{-1/x^4}$ which is the typical $C^{\infty}$ but not real analytic function, while $f(0+iy)=e^{-1/y^4}$ also)

In usual CA texts, one assumes stronger hypothesis like $f$ real differentiable with continuous differential on an $U$ plus C-R or at least $f$ continuous and the partial derivatives are continuous on $U$ too and deduce that $f$ is complex differentiable on $U$, but there is a theorem of Looman-Menchoff (strengthened by Montel) which is quite difficult and subtle (took a few decades to realize that the original proof of Looman had a gap and fix it) which says that $C-R$ plus continuity on $U$ (or just local boundness - Montel) are enough for complex differentiability as the $f$ here clearly fails continuity or boundness at the origin.

There is a very informative paper by Gray and Morris discussing this and much more:

["When is a Function that Satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann Equations Analytic?"](https://When%20is%20a%20Function%20that%20Satisfies%20the%20Cauchy-Riemann%20Equations%20Analytic?)

Comment: I believe the standard (not as general as you write) result, to which this function serves as a motivating example, is called [Looman-Menchoff theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Looman%E2%80%93Menchoff_theorem)

Comment: @tsnao yes Looman-Menchoff (and its strengthening by Montel) are the most well known general results, but they are difficult to prove as opposed the usual CA tetxbook proofs with stronger hypothesis

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

We rarely work with definitions alone; we use all the theorems available at our disposal. If I asked you to prove that $f(x)=e^{-1/x^4}$ is differentiable on $\Bbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, you had better tell me that the reason (in full) this is true is that:

- $x\mapsto x$ is differentiable (obvious from $\epsilon$-$\delta$)
- $x\mapsto x^4$ is thus differentiable, being a four-fold product of differentiable functions
- $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x^4}$ is differentiable away from the origin (the quotient of continuous functions is differentiable away from the zeros of the denominator)
- $x\mapsto -\frac{1}{x^4}$ is differentiable away from the origin (product of the constant function $-1$ with a differentiable function)
- $\exp:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is differentiable (a well-known fact)
- $x\mapsto e^{-1/x^4}$ is differentiable away from the origin (composition of differentiable functions is differentiable).

In the complex case $f:\Bbb{C}\setminus\{0\}\to\Bbb{C}$, $f(z)=e^{-1/z^4}$, the reasoning above works word for work once you replace $\Bbb{R}$ with $\Bbb{C}$. The sum, product, quotient, chain rules (compositions) are all stated and proved exactly as in the real case. So, no Cauchy-Riemann necessary here (and this is often an extremely inefficient way of doing things when you’re given nice simple explicit formulas $f(z)=\dots$, for exactly the reasons you mentioned). Once you know that the function is complex-differentiable, you can then state as a simple corollary that it must therefore satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed answer.